# How to create the hexadecimal complement?

Tags: java, hex

I have hexadecimal value and want to create the bitwise complement. Eg:

```
0x00 -> 0xFF
0xC4 -> 0x3B
```

The following test fails, but why?

```
@Test
public void testBitwiseComplement() {
    char[] buffer = new char[] {0x00, 0xff};
    assertEquals(buffer[0], ~buffer[1]); //expected 0, but was -256
    assertEquals(buffer[1], ~buffer[0]); //expected 255, but was -1
}
```

Comment: Try it on an array of bytes instead of chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitwise Negation Operator ~[Refer:https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java/langref/ch04_04.htm]

The bitwise negation operator (~) may appear as part of a unary expression. The type of the operand of the ~ operator must be an integer data type, or a compile-time error occurs. The ~ operator may perform a type conversion before it performs its computation. If the type of the operand is byte, short, or char, the operator converts its operand to int before producing a value. Otherwise the ~ operator produces a value of the same type as its operand.

```
public class BitwiseNegation {

 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    char a = 0xff;
    char b = 0x00 ;

    System.out.printf(">>>>>a HexaDecimal: %x Decimal: %d\n", (int)a, (int)a);
    System.out.printf(">>>>>b HexaDecimal: %x Decimal: %d\n", (int)b, (int)b);

    System.out.printf(">>>>>~a HexaDecimal: %x Decimal: %d\n", ~a, ~a);
    System.out.printf(">>>>>~b HexaDecimal: %x Decimal: %d\n", ~b, ~b); 
    }

}
```

Output:

```
>>>>>a HexaDecimal: ff Decimal: 255   
>>>>>b HexaDecimal: 0 Decimal: 0  
>>>>>~a HexaDecimal: ffffff00 Decimal: -256  
>>>>>~b HexaDecimal: ffffffff Decimal: -1
```

Since char is promoted to int for unary operators, the value 0xff becomes 0x000000ff which after bitwise complement becomes 0xffffff00. Now this number is a negative number (sign bit is 1) and by reversing the two's complement representation the number becomes -256. But the bitwise complement of 0x00 is -1. Hence the assertion fails.

So only for the values 0xffffffff and 0x00000000, their bitwise complements are also equal.

Comment: Sorry, I mean add an explanation of what the code is doing :)

Comment: I think you have included you explanation in the code box

Comment: Yes, this is my first answer and I had hard time formatting my post.

Comment: I sent potential edits, feel free to change what I did or edit it differently, and congrats on the first post!

Comment: Sure, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise complent in java does apply unary promotion where "char" operand is promoted to a int . https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2

Java int is a 4 byte SIGNED type and hence you see the difference .

```
~buffer[0]=11111111111111111111111111111111  is correct
~buffer[0]=11111111  is incorrect
```